# `package-menu-mark-delete` doesn't mark selected package

Tags: emacs, melpa

In `package-list-package`, I can't mark for deletion of installed package.

I've tried with <kbd>d</kbd> and `package-menu-mark-delete` also, but no mark showed up.

I can mark with <kbd>i</kbd> for install.

How to find where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you marked an installed item?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. I looked into detail page and it shows ` Status: Installed in` and so on.